# Managing Puppet certnames with dynamic servers

Tags: puppet, hiera

I have a puppet setup where each node manifest is named something like

```
/^web-\d+\.example\.com$/
```

We do this so we can spin up new servers for additional capacity and give each one a unique `certname` using the timestamp from when it was launched.

This is causing problems with the Hiera part of our Puppet setup since we can't do

```
:hierarchy:
  - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}"
  - common
```

since we can't predict what all the `certname`s will be. Right now we're just specifying each node type in the hierarchy, but we'd like to be able to add new node types without editing our `hiera.yaml` each time.

Is it possible to have some sort of dynamic lookup in our hierarchy that will allow us to have dynamically generated certnames without specifying every node type?

Comment: What about using a custom `facter` fact `role` for these machines (which might be `web`, for example) and extending the `hiera` hierarchy to match these?

Comment: That's what I ended up doing and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've updated both our hierarchy and custom facts to make this work. The hierarchy now includes

```
roles/%{::role}/${::environment}
```

and our nodes now include the following in `/etc/facter/facts/role.yaml`:

```
---
role: web
```